# How to complete word of selected from database using LEFT() function

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch field from database using LEFT() Function. I fetching **first 20 character** from description field. It fetched and getting result, but some time fetched incomplete word like this- **Some of your past qu**.

So, i want to displayed complete word like this- **Some of your past questions**

I know i fetching  first 20 character, that why i fetched incomplete word. But, if any solution is available for fetching complete word please suggest me.

```
<?php
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *, LEFT(descripation,20) AS descripation, LEFT(title,20) AS title FROM event WHERE status='Y'") or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            ?>
                <!--Event Thumb Start-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="msl-event">
                        <figure>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="admin_panel/event/<?php echo $row['image'];?>">
                            <div class="theme-bg date-box">
                                <?php 
                                    echo $newDate = date("F d,Y", strtotime($row['date']));
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <div class="text white_bg">                                             
                            <h4 class="event-title"><a href="event-detail.php?id=<?php echo ($row['id']);?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?>...</a></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $row['descripation'];?>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Event Thumb End-->
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about selecting 30 characters instead and then trimming the last word of the string?

```
<?php
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *, LEFT(description,30) AS description, LEFT(title,20) AS title FROM event WHERE status='Y'") or die("Could not retrieve image: " .mysqli_error($conn));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            //trim description
            $row['description'] = substr($row['description'], 0, strripos($row['description'], " ");
            //trim description
            ?>
                <!--Event Thumb Start-->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="msl-event">
                        <figure>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="admin_panel/event/<?php echo $row['image'];?>">
                            <div class="theme-bg date-box">
                                <?php 
                                    echo $newDate = date("F d,Y", strtotime($row['date']));
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                        <div class="text white_bg">                                             
                            <h4 class="event-title"><a href="event-detail.php?id=<?php echo ($row['id']);?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?>...</a></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $row['description'];?>...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Event Thumb End-->
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

FYI description is spelled description.